# Unity - Keeping UI centered no matter the screen resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to keep my UI looking the same no matter which resolution the screen is at I am running of 16:10 in my game view and I want the UI to stay the exactly the same and centered even if the screen resolution changes.

Screenshot of UI

[image: Screenshot of UI]

Comment: Did you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) explaining how to design UI for Multiple Resolutions? The secret is to understand and place correctly the anchors of your UI elements.

Comment: I more want to keep the UI on bigger resolutions so it stays centered and exactly the same in 16:10 as it does in larger resolutions, instead of stretching.

Answer (score 3):

For the UI in the screenshot, I assume you want it always at the bottom of the screen and always the width of the screen.

For always taking up the width of the screen, select your canvas and go to its canvas scalar component. 'Change UI Scale Mode' to 'Scale with Screen Size' and adjust Reference Resolution to a resolution that looks good for you. Then the canvas elements will be the same width on all resolutions.

[image]

For always staying centered at the bottom of the screen, select the UI elements themselves, or their parent if they have one. Change their anchor to bottom center.

[image]

For more information about how to design for all screen resolutions, check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) as Hellium suggested!

Comment: You can also have all those elements inside a parent RectTransform gameObject and adjust anchors.